# how to choose one value from a columns in "show column if" is qliksense

Tags: qliksense

I am trying to use the Only function in qliksense in order to pick only 1 value from a column to show. It's keeps showing all values. I also tried using Match along with GetFieldSelections.
The code:
Only(Ind) = 'Pop'
Match (GetFieldSelections ([Ind]), 'Pop')

I tried using the Only function as well as Match along with GetFieldSelections.
The code:

> Only(Ind) = 'Pop'
> Match (GetFieldSelections ([Ind]), 'Pop')

Comment: Can you elaborate a little further? Maybe a sample of your data and the desired result? Your code looks really weird.

Answer (score 0):

My column has many categories. I wish to choose only 1 category to represent in the Qliksense table dashboard, by using the Only(Ind) = 'Category_1' funcxtion (for examply. Meaning, I have data in my table, partitioned by categories. each table on the dashboard shows data about one different category (i.e the second dashboard will use Only(Ind) = 'Category_2'). I needed to use =If(Ind = 'Category_1', 'Category_1') - It workd perfectly.

Comment: Your `If()` statement makes sense. The `Only()` statement did not. You can also use a set expression like `Sum({<Ind={'Category_1'}>} data_column)`. This will perform a little better.